# C++ redefiniton of 'name' with a different type compiler warning

Tags: c++

Why do the compiler complain `redefiniton of 'reader' with a different type` when I try to pass an fstream object from main() into another class´s constructor for it to be read? I am aware of this is maybe i dumb way of doing it, I should really just have a string as parameter asking for filename then pass that into the fstream that I allocate in the constructor of the class. But anyways I am wondering why this don´t work, the compiler warning is cryptic.

my main function:

```
fstream reader;
reader.open("read.txt");
Markov(reader);
```

Constructor in Markov.h class:

```
class Markov {
public:
/** Constructor */
    Markov(fstream inStream) {
    Map<string, Vector<string> > array0;

    char ch;
    while (inStream.good())
    {
        ch = inStream.get();
        cout << ch << endl;
    }
    cout << "End: " << ch;

    order0(array0);
}
```

Comment: [Here's a hint.](http://ideone.com/kXdl0g)

Comment: Also (unrelated to this error but nonetheless important) your `Markov` constructor should take a reference: `Markov(fstream &inStream)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `Markov(reader);` is creating a variable called `reader` of type `Markov`. It is equivalent to the following: `Markov reader;`. Of course, since the compiler thinks you're declaring another variable called `reader`, it throws up this error. To create an instance of `Markov`, do this:

```
Markov m(reader);
```

This is an ambiguity in the grammar of C++ that is always taken as a declaration of a variable, rather than the construction of a temporary. In fact, you can have as many parentheses as you like around the variable name in your declaration: `Markov (((((reader)))))`.

`Markov(reader)` is of course perfectly fine syntax for creating a temporary of type `Markov`, as long as it isn't in a statement that could be parsed as a declaration. For example, if it's in the middle of an expression, you'll be okay. In the contrived expression `something += Markov(reader) - 6`, it can't be interpreted as a declaration.

Likewise, if there is more than one argument being passed to the constructor, `Markov(reader, writer)`, or if the single argument is not an identifier, `Markov("foo")`, it is not ambiguous.

If you're using a C++11 compiler, you can indeed create a temporary (although I see no reason to do it) that takes a single argument identifier using the new initialization syntax:

```
Markov{reader};
```

Comment: Oh... I did not think you had to create an instance of a class when calling it´s constructor in c++.

Comment: That's *precisely* what a constructor does - it initialises a new instance.

Comment: yes but 'Markov m(reader);' compared to 'Markov (reader);' in the first you got a refrence (m) you can use to access the class public functions. if I do Markov("static"); this should be fine right? but if i do 'string s = static Markov(s)' this would not work?

Comment: @TomLilletveit Added some more details to my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to pass that `fstream` by **reference**.

```
Markov(fstream& inStream)
```

And while you're at it, if you're only using it for input services, use an `ifstream&` instead.